# How can I run a python script using pythonbrew venv from the command line?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pythonbrew

I recently came across this in a cron script at my place of work:

`/bin/bash -c "[[ -s $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && source $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc && pythonbrew use 2.6.7 && pythonbrew venv use someapp && python /opt/someapp/bin/someapp.py"`

This is for a system-wide (multi-user) installation of Pythonbrew.

It works. But please tell me there's a better way.

#### Addendum

To clarify what I'm looking for: I'd like a one-line command to run my script though a virtualenv tied to pythonbrew. With virtualenv alone, I could do something like this:

```
/opt/someapp/venv/bin/python /opt/someapp/bin/someapp.py
```

What I don't want is another script to run my script (like that cron command above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it can be done by using the python binary directly from you `pythonbrew` virtual environment.
By default its in `~/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-<version>/<name of venv>/bin/python`
But I think you can change the path with an environmental variable.

So just change the first half of the line you added to reference the `pythonbrew` virtual environment python binary and it should work.

Comment: In my case, python binary turned out to be located at: `/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-<version>/<name of venv>/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

On the first line on your python script add a shebang (#!) followed by a path to your target python.  Then make the python script executable. It can then be executed directly from the command line (crontab, another bash script, whatever).

make a virtual env in your temp dir:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ virtualenv venv
```

the path to your python in that venv is /tmp/venv/bin/python

Using an editor create a simple script containing all of the following:

```
#!/tmp/venv/bin/python
print("hello world")
```

Save it in your home directory as "mypyscript.py"

make it executable:

```
$ chmod 755 mypyscript.py
```

Now you should be able to execute it using the filename directly on the command line:

```
$ ./mypyscript.py
hello world
```

Do this to your someapp.py substituting the relevant path to your python and that should work.

Answer (score 1):

The trick turned out to be locating the pythonbrew virtualenv's python binary. [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16594390/1093087) pointed me in the right direction. But here's a complete rundown for future reference:

With [pythonbrew installed](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew), I did the following (as `root` on the server):

```
pythonbrew install 2.6.6
pythonbrew switch 2.6.6
pythonbrew venv create --no-site-packages myapp
```

I had a pip freeze file, so I set up my virtualenv using that:

```
/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.6.6/myapp/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.pip
```

Now my python binary can be found at `/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.6.6/myapp/bin/python`. So to run my script:

```
/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.6.6/myapp/bin/python /opt/myapp/bin/myapp.py
```